# Probability integral transformation for a specified p.d.f

Tags: statistics, self-learning, statistical-inference

I am on page 163 of Degroot's probability and statistics (third edition), where he presents to me:

$g(y) = \frac{1}{2}(2-y)$ for $0<y<2$

He then mentions that the distribution function G of the given distribution is:

$G(y) = y - \frac{y^2}{4}$

Also, for $0<x<1$, the inverse function $y=G^{-1}(x)$ can be found by solving the equation $x=G(y)$ for y. The result is:

$$y=G^{-1}(x) = 2[1-(1-x)^{\frac{1}{2}}]$$

I cannot understand how he derives the values for $G(y)$ and $G^{-1}(x)$. I have only self-studied mathematics so this chapter has been difficult due to its wordyness and lack of examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$G(y)=\int\limits_0^yg(u)du$.  $G^{-1}(x)$ is the result of solving the quadratic equation $y-\frac{y^2}{4}-x=0$ for $y$.  General statement: $x=G(y)$ results in $y=G^{-1}(x)$

Comment: I wish the book explained it this way! Thank you